# Does Special Relativity require a "ruler postulate" analogous to the "clock postulate"?

Tags: special-relativity, spacetime, inertial-frames

It's fairly well known that the [clock postulate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clock_hypothesis) is needed in Special Relativity when dealing with accelerated clocks, so does something analogous exist when dealing with accelerated spatial displacements?

By this I mean: *the spatial distance between two identically co-accelerated points doesn't change in the instantaneous co-moving inertial frame.*

Answer (score 5):

I think you have slightly misinterpreted what the clock postulate says, and in doing so you have introduced an artificial distinction between time and length.

I think special relativity is best understood as a vacuum solution to Einstein's equation. Viewed this way, special relativity is a spacetime where the geometry is given by the Minkowski metric:

$$ ds^2 = -c^2dt^2 + dx^2 + dy^2 + dz^2 $$

The quantity $ds$ has units of length, and it's also often written as $ds^2 = -c^2d\tau^2$ where $d\tau$ has units of time and is called the proper time. The interpretation of $ds$ is that if you have some curve in spacetime then you can integrate $ds$ along the curve to give the length of the curve. For the observer moving along the curve, in their own locally inertial frame they are stationary so $dx = dy = dz = 0$ and so:

$$ ds^2 = -c^2d\tau^2 = -c^2dt^2 $$

and integrating this gives $s = ct$ or more intuitively $\tau = t$ i.e. the proper time, $\tau$, along the curve is the same as the time, $t$, shown on the clock carried by the moving observer.

The clock postulate says this is true whether the curve is a geodesic and the observer is moving freely, or whether the observer is being accelerated. Presumably it's called the *clock postulate* because it relates to the calculation of the proper time along the curve. But the quantity being calculated is the path length along the curve, and the proper time is simply another way of giving the length but divided by $c$. So the *clock postulate* could just as accurately be called the *length postulate*. Whatever you call it, it is simply the length of a curve.

This is why you do not need a separate *ruler postulate*, because the clock postulate is both a time and a length postulate depending on whether you're calculating $\tau$ or $s$.

Answer (score 3):

Barring its mathematical statement, the clock postulate, in my view, has a crucial physical content: it assumes the existence of ideal clocks whose behaviour is not influenced by their accelerations. In particular, a pair of these clocks with the same four velocity but different four accelerations works identically in a temporal neighbourhood of the considered event.
Therefore, yes, there is also a corresponding implicit postulate for (at least infinitesimal) ideal rulers. Otherwise one should always only use non accelerated rulers in the instantaneous inertial frame with the considered body at the considered event.